# Отсутствует обмен по Bluetooth между приложением android и "Intel galileo gen 2"

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, embedded, intel

Здравствуйте, написал приложение для андроид, которое отправляет данные на Bluetooth модуль "HC-06", которое подключено к отладочной плате "Intel galileo gen 2", данные корректно отправляются, но "Intel galileo gen 2" устойчиво не хочет их принимать. Вот сам скетч:

```
     void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
}

    void loop() {
     if (Serial.available() > 0){
        char incomingbyte = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(incomingbyte); 
      } 
    }
```

Пытался отправлять данные через терминал BT, который установлен на телефоне, но их я тоже не могу принять.
В чем может быть проблема?
Приложение под андроид устанавливает связь с HC-06 (видно по индикатору). Скорость стоит 9600.

Answer (score 1):

Самый первый вопрос - HC-06 правильно подключили к платке?
Второй вопрос - есть ли какая-то возможность проверить приходят ли данные на HC-06? Может он выдает какое-то прирывание или что-то подобное...
Попробуйте так же пройтись по разным baudrate'ам. Может ваш модуль установлен на другую скорость.
Так же можно попробовать отключить модуль и вместо него подключить какойнибудь USB-USART преоброзователь (например FTDI), подключить его к компьютеру и тестануть через терминал. Если Галилео будет принимать данные, то проблема в модуле, если нет - то проблема в Галилео и настройках / подключениях к UART'у.